# Installing Grapesjs version v0.21.1 editor broke

Tags: reactjs, next.js, editor, grapesjs

I have been trying to upgrade my Grapesjs editor(using react/nextjs) to the latest version.
But when I install v0.21.1 version editor is a completely broken.
There is no issue with v0.20.4.
Has anyone had this kind of problem before?

```
Object.defineProperty called on non-object
TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>) at __webpack_require__.r (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1704267939900:227:21) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/grapesjs/dist/grapes.mjs:1:21) at ./node_modules/grapesjs/dist/grapes.mjs (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/src_components_DeveloperHub_Hub_js.js:11579:1) at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1704267939900:683:31) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1704267939900:37:33) at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1704267939900:338:21) at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/DeveloperHub/Hub.js:15:67) at ./src/components/DeveloperHub/Hub.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/src_components_DeveloperHub_Hub_js.js:8422:1) at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1704267939900:683:31) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1704267939900:37:33) at Function.fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1704267939900:338:21)
```

I have tried to remove node-modules, but nothing changed.

Comment: You should not be uploading screenshots of error messages, instead copy paste the error text in a markdown code block

Comment: You mentioned deleting `node_modules` directory, but did you try deleting nextjs cache? It should be called `.next` or `_next`.

Comment: Thanks for the response
@zoran404 I believe I removed the .next file too, but I don't remember exactly.
I will copy-paste error as you said.